# Shadowing with x0vncserver - No mouse pointer

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, x11, xorg

I am working on a solution to shadow a user's X session in a multiuser desktop environment.  If one wants to shadow a session they use my script.  My script sets the proper XAUTHORITY environment variable for the display one wants to shadow then executes the following:

```
x0vncserver display=:XX MaxDisconnectionTime=30 SecurityTypes=VncAuth PasswordFile=/root/.vnc/passwd
```

I am not able to view the shadow user's mouse cursor.  I can see them clicking around but can not see the arrow.  I am not sure if it's my environment or  and issue with x0vnc.  I am running Oracle Linux (RedHat) with Sunray software.

I tried several VNC clients and can not see the mouse on any of them.  Has anyone else using x0vnc ran into this?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem just now, the VNC server is a Fedora 20 host, client is OS X Mavericks.

While this is not a way to get x0vncserver to show you a mouse cursor with any client, you can show a local cursor when using vncviewer as the client. It's also included in TigerVNC.

> vncviewer DotWhenNoCursor=1 localhost

#### Versions

Server: tigervnc-server-1.3.0-7.fc20.x86_64 (installed from base repo)
Client: 1.2.0 (installed from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/))